# Compile c/c++ program using gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am merging two complicated program, one written in c and the other in c++.

Here is a simplified situation.

My main program is written in c (main.c).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    printf("test!\n");
}
```

where test.h is the header of test.cpp, which is another program written by others in cpp.

test.h

```
#include <vector>

int test();
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

int test()
{
    return 1;
}
```

I try to compile main.c using the following command:
gcc -c main.c -o main.o -lstdc++

But I get the following error:
fatal error: no such file or dirctory #include

I don't want to change the codes of my main.c or test.cpp since they are much more complicated than that in this simplified example.

I am new to gcc, anyone can help to solve this problem?
Many thanks.

Comment: `<vecotr>` should probably be `<vector>` ...

Comment: are you using g++ or gcc?

Comment: `gcc main.c -o main.exe` if you are using gcc on windows

`g++ main.c -o main.exe` if you are using g++ on windows

Comment: On which operating system? With which commands?

Comment: Test should probably be marked `extern "C"`

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I have corrected the post. It is just a typo, and the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compile with `g++`, not `gcc` because it's C compiler and `<vector>` is a C++ header file (not mentioning `<vecotr>` which is a typo)

If you have to use C compiler, you have to remove all C++ dependencies from header files which are included from the C sources.

Answer (score 0):

[That's a typo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error): replace

```
#include <vecotr>
            ^^^
```

with

```
#include <vector>
```

Edit: plus you should compile with `g++`, not `gcc` since you're including a C++ header file.